# Serverless-framework Api Gateway output model

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I'm creating a serverless application and I want to:

1 [Create a model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-create-model.html)

2 Use it as Output model

I'm reading the serverless-framework documentation and the only reference to Model is about [request schema validation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#request-schema-validators)

Any idea or example?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is not implemented:

- https://github.com/GFG/serverless-apigateway-plugin/issues/10
- https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3896